# Highlight function (mouseover/mouseout event listeners) not working

Tags: javascript, function, dom, mouseover, event-listener

I followed some online instructions and some in-person recommendations about highlighting words, but I haven't been able to get anything to show. I should also mention that I'm not getting any error messages in the console.

Here's the .js:

```
let createWordElems = function() {

  for (var i = 0; i <= 54; i++) {
    var singleWord = document.createElement('span') // creating 'p' element, calling it singleWord
    singleWord.innerHTML = " " + shuffledWords[i]; // setting the content of the first word

    singleWord.addEventListener("click", clickFunc);
    // set onClick event for word

    var giantArrayElement = document.querySelector('.giant-array') // selecting .giant-array and storing it in var
    giantArrayElement.appendChild(singleWord); // appending singleWord to giantArrayElement
  }
}
createWordElems();



///// ======== ////// HIGHLIGHT ///// ======== //////

function highlight() {

  var selectSpan = document.querySelector('span')

  selectSpan.addEventListener("mouseover", function(evt) {
    evt.target.style.backgroundColor = "#ebce8e";
  });

  selectSpan.addEventListener("mouseout", function(evt) {
    evt.target.style.backgroundColor = "#473611";
  });
}

highlight();
```

Update:

```
window.addEventListener('onload',function() {
function highlight() {

  var selectSpan = document.querySelector('span')

  selectSpan.addEventListener("mouseover", function(evt) {
    evt.target.style.backgroundColor = "#ebce8e";
  });

  selectSpan.addEventListener("mouseout", function(evt) {
    evt.target.style.backgroundColor = "#473611";
  });

}
highlight();

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.addEventListener` function is often a bit tricky, because it often only works if the element has completely loaded. To avoid this problem, you should place your `highlight` function in

```
window.addEventListener('onload',function(){
  //your function here
}
```

to get your stuff to work.

Comment: I added an update underneath my original code. Is that what you meant by putting the highlight function in the window.add.etc line?

Comment: @Tsardines Yes, thats what i meant. Also consider to put your createWordElems function into that window.addEventListener as it also contains a addEventListener